# I am unable to import matplotlib, even after installing the compatible version of it

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have downloaded the matplotlib packages, but every time I run a program, it shows the module is not available. And, when I tried to install the packages again, it is showing that the requirement is already satisfied. What I am doing wrong? please help.

Comment: Make sure you're using the *Same Version of Python* for installing and importing

Comment: Are you installing and running in the same environment? Always use virtual environments when starting any Python project. Please provide a lore detailed question with the code and commands you're running.

Comment: As people already said, it's important you install and run matplotlib in the same Python. Install: `python3 -m pip install matplotlib`. Run: `python3 my_script.py`